# Apps script API sheet selection for execution

Tags: api

In the GAS code, there is a function to select sheet 2 of the spreadsheet, and when I run this code Apps Script API[method:scripts.run] using the google-api-php-client library in php, the response is returned, so I have confirmed that GAS is being executed.
However, when I run it in php, sheet 2 is not active.
Is it not possible to activate the sheet from the API?

```
function selectSheet() {

  try {

        let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var sheet = spread.getSheetByName('シート2');
        spread.setActiveSheet(sheet);

        var msg = "Apps Script function executed!!!"

        return msg

  } catch (error) {
    return "error:" + error.message;
  
  }

};
```

Sheet 2 should also be selected when executed from the Apps script API.